# How to send server-side variables to vue instance using webpack & vue-cli?

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js, server-side-rendering, vue-cli

I am currently making a project using vue-cli which generates a Node project with webpack. I can build all scripts and use the pug language within `.vue` files. When building, the project uses `HTML-Webpack-Plugin`, though, which outputs the code as static HTML with client-side scripts.

**How do I pass variables from the server-side to these client-side scripts?** I previously was using pug, which made this process easy, but since it now gets built into `.html` files, this can no longer be done.

I have two attempts, both suboptimal:

### 1. Send variables into clientside scripts

```
script.
  const clinetSideVar = `!{serverSideVar}`;
```

The problem with this approach is that I cannot pass this variable into the vue instance, since it gets obfuscated when built and I have no way of accessing it (or do I? I haven't found a way).

### 2. Using AJAX requests

I could also make a restful API for server-side site data and retrieve it using AJAX, but this seems like a real hack and this would lose quite a bit of performance over just sending the data plainly through a pug template (with no. 1 I'd too, since client-side JS would have to insert the data into the DOM).

Comment: what is `{serverSideVar}`? is it one file path or something else which will not be changed after build?

Comment: No, it is a variable that is sent with the web request, this is pug syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using **JSONP** (since your index.html is built ahead of time in Vue-cli).

**In your public/index.html** (which is a template)

```html
<head>
    ...
  <script>function getServerData(data) { window.__SERVER_DATA__ = data; }</script>
  <script src="/api/server-data.json?callback=getServerData"></script>
</head>
```

**In your Node Express routes definition**

```js
const app = express();

// ...

app.get('/api/server-data.json', (req, res) => {
  res.jsonp({
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar'
  });
});
```

Then just access `window.__SERVER_DATA__` from within any Vue component.